# What is Broken relative links?

Tags: seo, web

Refer to this link
http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=76329

I don't understand the following Paragraph.  Can you illustarte it? and what is broken relative links?, how that happens?

> Broken relative links. Broken relative links can often cause infinite
>   spaces. Frequently, this problem arises because of repeated path
>   elements. For example:
>
> http://www.example.com/index.shtml/discuss/category/school/061121/html/interview/
>   category/health/070223/html/category/business/070302/html/category/community/070413/html/FAQ.htm

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take a closer look at your example link. Due to poor linking structure, probably due to a bad use of `../` the URL is mangled and looks like it is actually three times deeper into the actual file structure then it really is.

Using full URLs (including the domain name) or starting from the absolute document root (`/`) are the best ways to keep this from happening.